# WPF treeview with databinding using multiple data sources

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a tree view which is used by 2 different sources (Mission, Target) depending on the mode the GUI is in. Only 1 source is displayed at any one time

Class information:

**Mission Class**

```
public class Mission
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Target> PotentialTargets { get; set; }
    public List<Target> SelectedTargets { get; set; }
    public List<Operation> OpList { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

**Operation Class**

```
public class Operation
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

**Target**

```
public class Target
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public TargetType Type { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

**TargetType**

```
public enum TargetType
{
    Star,
    Line
}
```

I am trying to achieve the following display on the TreeView when setting the itemSource to a different source.

**Mission Source**

```
- Mission_1(Name)
   - Potential_Target
       - Target_1(Label)
       - Target_2(Label)
   - Selected_Target
       - Target_1(Label)
   - Operation
       - Op_1(Name)
- Mission_2(Name)
   - Potential_Target
       - Target_1(Label)
       - Target_4(Label)
   - Selected_Target
       - Target_4(Label)
   - Operation
       - Op_1(Name)
```

**Target Source**

```
- Priority_1(Priority)
    - Star(TargetType)
       - Star_Target_1(Label)
    - Line(Type)
       - Line_Target_1(Label)
- Priority_2(Priority)
    - Star(TargetType)
       - Star_Target_2(Label)
       - Star_Target_3(Label)
```

All help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some base class to represent your tree nodes in `TreeView`.
For example you can declare you classes like this:

**ABaseNode**

```
// Base class to provide access to nodes Children
public abstract class ABaseNode
{
    private ObservableCollection<ABaseNode> children;

    public ObservableCollection<ABaseNode> Children
    {
        get { return children ?? (children = new ObservableCollection<ABaseNode>()); }
        set { children = value; }
    }
}
```

**LabeledNode**

```
//Simple node with label to display
public class LabeledNode : ABaseNode
{
    public LabeledNode(string label)
    {
        Label = label;
    }

    public string Label { get; private set; }
}
```

**Mission Class**

```
public class Mission : LabeledNode
{
    public Mission(string label) : base(label)
    {
        PotentialTargetsNode = new LabeledNode("PotentialTargets");
        Children.Add(PotentialTargetsNode);

        SelectedTargetsNode = new LabeledNode("SelectedTargets");
        Children.Add(SelectedTargetsNode);

        OpListNode = new LabeledNode("Operation");
        Children.Add(OpListNode);
    }

    public LabeledNode PotentialTargetsNode { get; private set; }
    public LabeledNode SelectedTargetsNode { get; private set; }
    public LabeledNode OpListNode { get; private set; }
}
```

**Operation Class**

```
public class Operation : LabeledNode
{
    public Operation(string label) : base(label)
    {
    }
    //other properties
}
```

**Target Class**

```
public class Target : LabeledNode
{
    public Target(string label) : base(label)
    {
    }

    public TargetType Type { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

**PriorityNode Class**

```
public class PriorityNode : LabeledNode
{
    public PriorityNode(int priority) : base("Priority: " + priority)
    {
        StarTargetsNode = new LabeledNode("Star");
        Children.Add(StarTargetsNode);

        LineTargetsNode = new LabeledNode("Line");
        Children.Add(LineTargetsNode);
    }

    public LabeledNode StarTargetsNode { get; private set; }
    public LabeledNode LineTargetsNode { get; private set; }
}
```

**Xaml of MainWindow contents**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Mission source" Click="MissionButtonClick"/>
    <Button Content="Target source" Click="TargetsButtonClick"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" Height="250" ItemsSource="{Binding Missions}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LabeledNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LabeledNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

**Data initialization**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Mission> Missions { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<PriorityNode> TargetsByPriority { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mission = new Mission("Mission1");
        mission.PotentialTargetsNode.Children.Add(new Target("Target1") {Type = TargetType.Line, Priority = 1});
        mission.PotentialTargetsNode.Children.Add(new Target("Target2") {Type = TargetType.Star, Priority = 2});
        mission.SelectedTargetsNode.Children.Add(new Target ("SelectedTarget") { Type = TargetType.Line, Priority = 1 });
        mission.OpListNode.Children.Add(new Operation("Op1"));

        Missions = new ObservableCollection<Mission> { mission };

        var priorityNode = new PriorityNode(1);

        priorityNode.StarTargetsNode.Children.Add(new Target("Target3") { Type = TargetType.Star, Priority = 1 });

        priorityNode.LineTargetsNode.Children.Add(new Target("Target1") { Type = TargetType.Line, Priority = 1 });
        priorityNode.LineTargetsNode.Children.Add(new Target("Target2") { Type = TargetType.Line, Priority = 1 });

        TargetsByPriority = new ObservableCollection<PriorityNode> { priorityNode};

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void MissionButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView.ItemsSource = Missions;
    }

    private void TargetsButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView.ItemsSource = TargetsByPriority;
    }
}
```

Now click the buttons to change your `TreeView` `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Edited: Add missing PriorityNode class.

Comment: And why he need LabeledNode? We can create templates for Target, Operation etc types.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed.

Comment: I just notice that with this solution, I can't add additional controls that only some classes have it. For example, I would like to add a colored border to "Priority" (in target) label or total number of operations in OpListNode (in Mission). Any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to get the priority with color border out by adding a new HierarchicalDataTemplate for PriorityNode. As for number of operations, I manipulate it when creating the mission object.